# Oracle join using two possible column data

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle12c

I work with an Oracle 12 database that represents mainframe data.  Here is my question.

We have two levels of heirarchy, "System" and "Prin".  Imagine them as state and county in the USA.  Sometimes, a client will build everything at System level and all of it's children will always referece the System configuration.  Other clients built at Prin level, and and child of the prin will first have to look at the PRIN level data for configuration, if prin is not built in the table, then it defaults to the system level config.   Pretty easy.

Here's where i can't get the table join to work.  A single client can have some systems built at the systems level, and others at the prin level. How can i dynamically join when i am not sure what configuration the client is using in that specific prin?

Example:

```
WITH tbl as (
select 80 SYSTEM, 0 PRIN, 2 DATA from dual
union
select 80 , 1 , 3  from dual
union
select 80 , 2 , 4 from dual
)
```

now if i have an item located in system 80 prin 3... it will need the 0 prin data because 0 denotes the "system" config.

so if i have prin 1, i want data "3".  if i have prin 2, data "4" , if i have prin 8, i want data "2" because there is no prin 8 config built.

See where I am trying to get?

So when i do

```
select *
from tbl t
inner join tbl2 tt on t.sys = tt.sys and prin =  ?????
```

how do I say "if prin is built in tbl, use prin, otherwise default to prin = 0"

I know this is a badly stated question. So please ask more specifics and i will try to answer quickly.  This is affecting multiple tables.

Comment: Welcome aboard. I think you might be better restating your question/code using your State and County example as something we can all relate to more easily. I think your example code has too much domain specific information so for us to understand it requires a level of knowledge about your particular system and industry etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty ugly, but then so is the data model...

```
with
     tbl ( s, prim, val ) as (
       select 80, 0, 2 from dual union all
       select 80, 1, 3 from dual union all
       select 80, 2, 4 from dual
     ),
     inputs ( s, prim ) as (
       select 80, 1 from dual union all
       select 80, 5 from dual
     )
select t.s, i.prim i_prim, t.prim tbl_prim, t.val
from   tbl t join inputs i
             on t.s = i.s
             and
             (    t.prim = i.prim 
               or t.prim = 0 
               and not exists ( select * from tbl 
                                where s = i.s and prim = i.prim ))
;

   S     I_PRIM   TBL_PRIM        VAL
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
  80          5          0          2
  80          1          1          3

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and did not affect the query performance by much more than 5-10 seconds.  Thank you very much.

Comment: ^^^ to add, the tables were about 2M rows joining to about a 100k row. So 10 seconds was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would disadvise you from using a (complex) JOIN with OR-condition on slightly bigger tables (50k+), as the execution plan may totally go nuts from my own experience.

Under such circumstances rather use a Union `(select cond1_match) union all (select cond2_default)` ordered/ranked and select the first row or use a JOIN like

```
select coalesce(a1.prin, a2.prin) 
from (select cond1_match) a1 
full join (select cond2_default) a2
```

And if understand you right, that you have just one number as input and want to join another datatable, then my suggestion would look like this

```
with
     tbl ( SYSTEM, PRIN, DATA ) as (
       select 80, 0, 2 from dual union all
       select 80, 1, 3 from dual union all
       select 80, 2, 4 from dual
     ),
     tbl2 (SYSTEM, PRIN, OTHERDATA) as (
       select 80, 0, 99 from dual union all
       select 80, 1, 333 from dual union all
       select 80, 2, 444 from dual
     )
select t.system, t.prin, t.data, tt.otherdata
from tbl t
inner join tbl2 tt on t.system = tt.system and t.prin = tt.prin 
where t.prin = (select nvl(max(prin), 0) from tbl where system = t.system and prin = :pri)
;
```

system + prin have to be unique or max() would be random

:pri = 5

```
SYSTEM  PRIN    DATA    OTHERDATA
------  ----    ----    ---------
80      0       2       99
```

:pri = 2

```
SYSTEM  PRIN    DATA    OTHERDATA
------  ----    ----    ---------
80      2       4       444
```

Only guessing about `tbl2` and the join condition, but that's basically how I was told to look up data or use a default if no_data_found in SQL